# JPA one to many mapping based on a query

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I may be going at this from the wrong direction but here is my scenario.

essentially I have a a header and a detail entity.
they have a one to many relationship and i have them mapped as such.  all of this is working fine.

however there are several details records which are set to inactive.

can i make a mapping such that it will only join the active detail records records by utilizing a query or some other means?

I can add some code if it helps.

I am using hibernate and annotations.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Heres how it looks to make this work

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tourHeader", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Where(clause="it_curr_rec='Y'")
private Set<TourItinerary> itineraries;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at Hibernate docs [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-collection), it seems that you can use `@Where` annotation to achieve your goal.

Also see this [javadoc on @Where](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/).